# Accuraccy for prediction

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I'm new to machine learning and I'm trying to learn the process and have started by playing around with Weka. When I load the data in Weka and start the classification, the software shows values such as below:

```
Correctly Classified Instances         416               39.6568 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       633               60.3432 %
Kappa statistic                          0.091 
Mean absolute error                      0.4371
Root mean squared error                  0.4663
Relative absolute error                 98.4524 %
Root relative squared error             98.9763 %
Coverage of cases (0.95 level)         100      %
Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)     100      %
Total Number of Instances             1049     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

             TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
             0.310    0.231    0.377      0.310    0.340      0.084    0.554     0.448     16-18
             0.271    0.167    0.460      0.271    0.341      0.123    0.501     0.359     19+
             0.599    0.511    0.382      0.599    0.467      0.084    0.570     0.395     All Age
Weighted Avg.    0.397    0.306    0.407      0.397    0.384      0.098    0.541     0.399
```

By taking a look at these values, I can assume that I have bad data since the number of Correctly Classified Instances is 37.65 and there is a high error rate. But the TP Rate and Precision are around an acceptable level.

This makes me confused, I want to know how I can judge the model based on these numbers? Does it mean my data is badly preprocessed?

Comment: I think your 0.397 TP rate and 0.407 precision with 0.384 F-measure are far from "acceptable level". I think you need to work with your data.

Comment: @IstvanNagy: What is the minimum value for acceptable level?

Comment: it is depend on your aim/task. But, in my opinion below 50 is not acceptable.

Comment: @IstvanNagy: just to avoid confusion: I'm very convinced you mean 0.5 ;)

Comment: @CAFEBABE yep, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a confusion matrix to get the accuracy and precision. Below is the link. Hope it helps.

http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/confusion_matrix/confusion_matrix.html

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot :)